# How to interpret lmer summary statistics

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme

Just to give you a bit of a background understanding I'm doing a study on how the construction of a motorway affects badger extraterritorial excursions. I have calculated the average excursion distance (continuous response) by each badger for each month meaning I have multiple entries involving the same badgers which is why I need to use an lmer (to account for the individual effects I believe are present). I have four data sets, one from before construction of the motorway, one from during construction, one for after construction and one which includes all the data from before, during and after construction. I am also interested to see what effect sex and age cohort (juvenile, young adult and older adult) have.
I have set up a lmer model since i have a continuous response variable.

```
lmerbefore1<-lmer(log10(average_ete_m)~sex*age_cohort+(1|name), data=dat1)
summary(lmerbefore1)
    Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: log10(average_ete_m) ~ sex * age_cohort + (1 | name)
   Data: dat1

REML criterion at convergence: 376.2

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.7405 -0.5848 -0.0394  0.6479  3.6772 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 name     (Intercept) 0.05861  0.2421  
 Residual             0.14611  0.3822  
Number of obs: 339, groups:  name, 43

Fixed effects:
                           Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                 2.14947    0.09881  21.755
sexF                       -0.11054    0.14418  -0.767
age_cohortYoung Adult      -0.04557    0.10609  -0.430
age_cohortOlder Adult       0.03981    0.14322   0.278
sexF:age_cohortYoung Adult  0.06488    0.15086   0.430
sexF:age_cohortOlder Adult -0.27023    0.19581  -1.380

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) sexF   ag_cYA ag_cOA sF:_YA
sexF        -0.685                            
ag_chrtYngA -0.769  0.527                     
ag_chrtOldA -0.589  0.403  0.679              
sxF:g_chrYA  0.541 -0.770 -0.703 -0.478       
sxF:g_chrOA  0.431 -0.617 -0.497 -0.731  0.695
```

I cant really make sense of these results and not sure if they're telling me anything so any explanation would be appreciated.
I also did an anova but I'm not sure what the F values are telling me if this makes sense to do at all.

```
anova(lmerbefore1)
Analysis of Variance Table
               Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
sex             1 0.21460 0.21460  1.4687
age_cohort      2 0.31836 0.15918  1.0894
sex:age_cohort  2 0.82447 0.41224  2.8213
```

i have done the same thing with all three before, during and after data sets and also did a more complex model for the full data set which takes into account the interaction with roadworks

```
 lmertotal1<-lmer(log10(average_ete_m)~sex*age_cohort*roadworks+(1|name), 
data=fulldat)
```

Comment: None of the variables in the linear model (fixed or random) are statistically significant.  Only the intercept is significant.

Comment: I recommend the `intervals()` command for confidence intervals due to the ongoing debate about interpreting p-values. Notice that `R` reports Tau error values in SD format.

Comment: Since the interaction is not significant I would remove it and run the model with just the main effects.

Comment: @Micheal Chernick Just to clarify, is my intercept significant due to the high positive t-value? So does this mean that the the only significant difference lies in my response variable? And if this is the case does that mean this difference is caused by individual differences from +(1|name)?

Comment: @Glen do you know the interaction is not significant based on the  F value from the anova or how can you tell? i thought the interaction had to be of some importance as when i build the model without the interaction the AIC is bigger than the AIC of the model which includes the interaction.

Comment: @JamesO'Hara Yes, looking at the F-values and the T-values nothing is significant.